# How to use PCNTL to call a php function in parallel

Tags: php, parallel-processing

I have around 10 different requests for different servers and used to get the response sequentially in respective to the function call in my website.

Now, I want to call my function in parallel for different server request. Once I get the first response from any of the servers, then want to stop the the remaining processes.

Currently I am calling my function like so:

```
my_launch(1);
my_launch(2);
my_launch(3);
my_launch(4);
my_launch(5);
my_launch(6);
my_launch(7);
my_launch(8);
my_launch(9);
my_launch(10);
```

This executes sequentially; how can I run this code in parallel using PCNTL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**About PCNTL availibility**

PHP has some PCNTL features built in but they are not enabled by default.

From [php.net pcntl installation instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php):

> You have to compile the CGI or CLI version of PHP with --enable-pcntl configuration option when compiling PHP to enable Process Control support.

---

**Regarding parallelization**

If you know the number of cores on your machine, then I would suggest dividing the work into that many divisions. Process control only works on *nix-like systems, so you probably have the `nproc` command available:

```
$numberOfProcessors = `nproc`;
```

You [fork](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) to get the proper number of processes running, divide the work between them and off you go. Dividing the work might be difficult, but I'm sure you'll figure it out.

---

**Code dump**

I was feeling generous so I went ahead and coded most of it for you. Be sure to understand it because it isn't quite finished.

Notes:

- Grabs the number of available processors by calling `nproc`, so if you don't have that utility you should replace it with the number of processes you want to make.
- If you have more processors available than requested iterations it will not break.  It simply uses fewer processors.
- If the number of processes doesn't divide evenly into the number of the iterations, the parent process will pick up the remaining iterations.
- **Does not stop after the first result is available.** In order to do this, you will need to have one process per iteration. The main process should call [pcntl_wait](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-wait.php) for when the first one finishes and kill the others.

Code:

```
$procs = `nproc`;
$iterations = 10;
$pids = array();
$iproc = -1;

if ($procs > $iterations) {
    $procs = $iterations;
}

function my_launch($i, $proc) {
    echo "Process $proc ran iteration $i.\n";
}

$pid = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $procs; $i++) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid > 0) {
        // I am the parent process
        $pids[$pid] = $pid;

    } elseif ($pid == -1) {
        //error occurred, use available processes only
        $nproc = $i;
        break;

    } else {
        //I am the child process.
        $iproc = $i;
        break;
    }
}

$nproc = !empty($nproc) ? $nproc : $procs;

if ($nproc == 0) {
    echo "NOTICE: Process could not be forked; proceeding in serial.\n";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
        my_launch($i, $iproc);
    }
    exit;
}

if ($nproc != $procs) {
    echo "NOTICE: Only using $nproc processes out of the hoped $procs.\n";
}

$iterationsPerProcess = (int) ($iterations / $nproc);

// children do the main work.
if ($pid == 0) {
    $stopAt = $iterationsPerProcess * ($iproc + 1);

    for ($i = ($iproc * $iterationsPerProcess); $i < $stopAt; $i++) {
        my_launch($i, $iproc);
    }
}

if ($pid > 0) {
    // parent process picks up the remainder of the work
    $i = $nproc * $iterationsPerProcess;
    for (; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
        my_launch($i, "Main");
    }

    //wait for children to finish
    $status = -1;
    foreach ($pids as $createdIndex => $pid) {
        pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status);
    }
}
```